# Object is not receiving in parent component when event is emitted in child component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, angular-event-emitter

I trying to send the 2 values to parent component from child component.Event is emitting onSubmit but the object is not receiving values in parent component.

```js
// child component

@Output() submitEvent = new EventEmitter < object > ();

//here I am emitting the values

onSubmit() {

  const startdate = moment(this.angForm.get('start_date').value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  const enddate = moment(this.angForm.get('end_date').value).format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:00');
  const obj = {
    startdate: moment(this.angForm.get('start_date').value).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),

    enddate: moment(this.angForm.get('end_date').value).format('YYYY-MM-DD 23:59:00')
  }
  this.submitEvent.emit({
    startdate,
    enddate
  });
}
```

```html
//parent component

<app-filter-panel (submitEvent)="eventrecive(dateobj)"></app-filter-panel>
```

```js
eventrecive(dateobj) {
  console.log(dateobj);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `$event` as parameter for *event emitter* handler in the parent *component*.

```
<app-filter-panel (submitEvent)="eventrecive($event)"></app-filter-panel>
                                             ^^^^^^^
```

For `EventEmitter` *events* the emitted value is available as `$event`.